# How do I add text at the beginning of a file?

Tags: powershell, scripting

I have the following Powershell script:

```
cd C:\Users\test_user\Desktop\test-code\update-fields-script\
$fileDirectory="C:\Users\test_user\Desktop\test-code\update-fields-script\objects\"
foreach($file in Get-ChildItem $fileDirectory)
{
    ([xml] (Get-Content -Raw $fileDirectory\$file)).CustomObject.fields.fullName -join ', ' | Set-Content "C:\Users\test_user\Desktop\test-code\update-fields-script\finalized_output\$file"
    Add-Content -Value '<entry key="extractSQL" value="' -Path "C:\Users\test_user\Desktop\test-code\update-fields-script\finalized_output\$file"
    Add-Content -Value 'FROM $file"/>' -Path "C:\Users\test_user\Desktop\test-code\update-fields-script\finalized_output\$file"
}
```

How can I make the first 'Add-Content' command appear at the beginning of a file as opposed to the end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may seem too simple, but you could just move that line before the previous line, change it to `Set-Content`, and change the previous line to `Add-Content`.

```
cd C:\Users\test_user\Desktop\test-code\update-fields-script\
$fileDirectory="C:\Users\test_user\Desktop\test-code\update-fields-script\objects\"
foreach($file in Get-ChildItem $fileDirectory)
{
    Set-Content -Value '<entry key="extractSQL" value="' -Path "C:\Users\test_user\Desktop\test-code\update-fields-script\finalized_output\$file"
    ([xml] (Get-Content -Raw $fileDirectory\$file)).CustomObject.fields.fullName -join ', ' | Add-Content "C:\Users\test_user\Desktop\test-code\update-fields-script\finalized_output\$file"
    Add-Content -Value 'FROM $file"/>' -Path "C:\Users\test_user\Desktop\test-code\update-fields-script\finalized_output\$file"
}
```

Comment: I like simple. Thanks!